# Eclipse 4.4 new class wizard does not extend full class name

Tags: eclipse, class, extends, wizard

I use the new class wizard in Eclipse 4.4.2 to create a class called MyClass in package impl that extends from a class called MyClass in package base. The class wizard generates the following code with error messages (due to class name conflict):

```
package impl;
import base.MyClass;
public abstract class MyClass extends MyClass {
}
```

However, in previous versions of Eclipse the new class wizard generated the following code without errors:

```
package impl;
public abstract class MyClass extends base.MyClass {
  @override
  public void myOp() throws MyException {   
  }
}
```

As far as I know I'm using default settings for both versions of Eclipse. Is there a setting in Eclipse 4.4.2 to force the package name to be added to the extended class name?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Eclipse? The current version is Neon.3 (4.6.3) on which I cannot reproduce your behaviour. Perhaps this is a bug in 4.4.2? You can also try the `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Add Import instead of qualified name` preference which exists in 4.6.3 but is not really applicable here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that for 4.6 Johannes. I was trying to avoid updating but will probably have to now.